# QGIS 3.24 - Copying attribute table data doesn't capture new calculations

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I frequently grab data from layer attribute tables, then paste in Excel for summarization purposes (I find Excel functions like Pivot Tables easier to use than QGIS's built-in statistics functions). For example, often I want to find total lengths of similar line features so in QGIS I'll run a "$length" formula on a new column. Once populated, I'll select all the data, click the copy button, and paste this to Excel, only to find that for whatever reason, the newly-calculated length data did not make it into the clipboard. I can save the layer, stop editing, what have you; sometimes this seems to work, sometimes not. The only true fix I've noted is saving the project, exiting QGIS, and relaunching.
Is this a bug?

Comment: Are you using virtual fields? What is your data source/provider? Can you make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Does it happen with any kind of dataset?  We had similar infrequent problems with ArcMap for years and figured it was caching the changes while the copy to Excel was reading from the disk file.  It even happened with an exported dbf table.  I think we had to close all instances of ArcMap but sometimes reboot.  I seem to recall tech support said undo/redo might cause it.  I don't recall having the problem with QGIS.